# $\int_0^1|f(x)|dx=0$ if and only if $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\Bbb R$ is a continuous function and **not negative** function such that
$$
\int_0^1f(x)dx=0
$$
then could exist $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)$ is not zero? I know [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050904/show-that-int-acfxdx-0-for-all-c-in-a-b-if-and-only-if-fx-0) result but unfortunately it does not help now. So is the result still true with my restrictive hypothesis? if not could you give a counterexample, plese? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135448/discussion-on-question-by-antonio-maria-di-mauro-int-01fxdx0-if-and-onl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and let $x_0 \in [0, 1]$ be such that $f(x_0) > 0$.

If $f(y) > \frac {f(x_0)} {2}$ for all $y \in [0, 1]$, then

$$
\int_0^1 f(x) dx > \frac {f(x_0)} {2} \cdot 1 = \frac {f(x_0)} {2} > 0
$$

Otherwise, $f(y) \le \frac{f(x_0)}{2}$ for some $y \in [0, 1]$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, $f$ is onto $\big[ f(y), f(x_0) \big]$.

Now, since $f$ is continuous, $N = f^{-1} \big(\frac{f(x_0)}{2}, f(x_0) \big)$ is open, and $a = f^{-1}\big(\frac{3}{4} \cdot f(x_0) \big) \in N$ (since $f$ is onto). Hence there exists an open ball $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) \subseteq N$, whence $f(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) \subseteq f(N) = \big(\frac{f(x_0)}{2}, f(x_0) \big)$ (equality, since $f$ is onto).

I.e., $f(y) > \frac {f(x_0)} {2} > 0$ for all $y \in (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$. But then since $f \ge 0$ on all of $[0, 1]$ ($f = |f|$),

$$
\int_0^1 f(x) dx \ge
\int_{a - \epsilon}^{a + \epsilon} f(x) dx >
2 \epsilon \cdot \frac{f(x_0)}{2} =
\epsilon \cdot f(x_0)
> 0
$$

**EDIT**:

There's a better argument here. Let $B = B_{\frac{f(x_0)}{2}}\big( f(x_0) \big) = \big(\frac{1}{2}f(x_0), \frac{3}{2} f(x_0)\big)$. Then $f(x_0) \in B$, $N = f^{-1}(B)$ is open by continuity of $f$, and $x_0 \in N$. Now we may find an open ball $(x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon) \subseteq N$, whence $f(x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon) \subseteq f(N) \subseteq \big(\frac{1}{2}f(x_0), \frac{3}{2} f(x_0)\big)$. I.e., $f(y) > \frac{1}{2} f(x_0)$ for all $y \in (x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon)$. Now, as before,

$$
\int_0^1 f(x) dx \ge
\int_{x_0 - \epsilon}^{x_0 + \epsilon} f(x) dx >
2 \epsilon \cdot \frac{f(x_0)}{2} =
\epsilon \cdot f(x_0)
> 0
$$

This avoids altogether the whole issue of $f$ having to be onto the interval $\big( \frac{1}{2}f(x_0), f(x_0) \big)$ (and indeed, is a much shorter proof).

Comment: Not quite.   The usual version is that if $f(x_0)>0$ then there is a neighborhood $(x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon)$ on which $f(y) \geq \frac12f(x_0)>0$.  Then conclude that $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx \geq \int_{x_0 - \epsilon}^{x_0 + \epsilon} f(x) dx  \geq 2\epsilon f(x_0)>0.$$  You are simply assuming that a positive function has a positive integral (which is correct of course, but needs proof).

Comment: @B.S.Thomson yes, I know that a positive function has a positive integral requires proof. I wasn't going to elaborate, unless OP asked for further clarification.

Comment: @JoeShmo I think you should have said that if there was exist $y\in[0,1]$ such that $f(y)\neq 0$ then by the continuity of $f$ there would be exist $\delta>0$ such that $$|f(y)-f(x)|<f(y)$$ for all $x\in(y-\delta,y+\delta)$ so that we conclude that $f$ is positive in this interval. Now $f$ is not negative so that the integrals $$\int_0^{y-\delta} f,\int_{y+\delta}^1$$ are positive so that $$0=\int_0^1 f=\int_0^{y-\delta}f+\int_{y-\delta}^{y+\delta}f+\int_{y+\delta}^1f\ge\int_{y-\delta}^{y+\delta}f>0$$ because the integral of a  **strictly** positive function must be **strictly** postivie.

Comment: @JoeShmo However I have to confide you that only understand that the integral of a **strictly** positive function on a compact set is surely **strictly** positive but I never tried seriously why this holds also for open set...

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I'm not sure your paraphrasal of the original argument here helps. In addition, you really need to prove that "the integral of a strictly positive function must be strictly positive". See @ B. S. Thomson's comment.

Comment: @JoeShmo If by my paraphrasal comment is not clear why $f$ is positive, here an expalation: if $|f(y)-f(x)|<f(y)$ for any $x\in(y-\delta,y+\delta)$ then $f(y)-f(x)<f(y)$ for any $x\in(y-\delta,y+\delta)$ so that clearly $f(x)>0$ for any $x\in(y-\delta,y+\delta)$.

Comment: @JoeShmo Anyway I agree with your sentence: «You really need to prove that *the integral of a strictly positive function must be strictly positive*» So exactly for this unfortunately I cannot accept your answer: I never understood why the integral of a positive function is positive on an **open** set: this is really a mystery to me. Forgive me.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro no, I mean that it's clear that $\int_0^1 f \ge \int_A f$, for any $A \subseteq [0,1]$, since $f = |f|$. As far as the second question, I think B.S.Thompson already answered it, but I will try to elaborate on why that holds in an edit.

Comment: @JoeShmo Okay, all clear now: question approved and upvoted. Thanks very much for your assistance!!!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I had actually edited the question one more time. I skipped an important point in my previous argument. It should be complete now. Take a look.

Comment: @JoeShmo I read: very fine!

Answer (score 3):

To follow the proof that Tommy1234 suggested to me in the comments above.

Let $F:[0,1]\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be the integral function of $f$, that is
$$
F(x):=\int_0^x f(t)dt\,.
$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus and the non-negativity of $f$, $$F'(x)=f(x)\geq 0$$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, so $F(x)$ is non-decreasing there. Thus,
$$
F(0)\le F(x)\le F(1)
$$
for any $x\in[0,1]$. However, by the assumption,
$$
F(0)=F(1)=0,
$$
so we conclude that
$
F(x)\equiv 0
$
in $[0,1]$. This implies that $$f(x)=F'(x)\equiv 0$$ as well.

Comment: @AlvinL $F(1)=0$ for hypothesis: read the question.

Comment: @Snoop I did not say **directly** that $F(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ implies that $f$ is zero: I gave appropriate argumentations so that why it shall be circular?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Right, sorry. You've concluded that $F(x)$ is identically zero. So derivative of a constant map must be zero.

Comment: @AlvinL Sure, right.